# Turn a simple recursive function into pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I'm a complete beginner so this is probably a stupid question.
I want to turn this recursive function that sums all integers to a function with pattern matching

```
sumOfNumbers :: Int -> Int
sumOfNumbers n
   | n == 0        = 0
   | otherwise   = n + sumOfNumbers(n -1)
```

Which I'm guessing would look like this.

```
sumOfNumbers :: Int -> Int
sumOfNumbers n == 0    = 0        
sumOfNumbers _  = n + sumOfNumbers(n -1)
```

My attempt is wrong as a I get

> Parse error in pattern

error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

simple!

```hs
sumOfNumbers :: Int -> Int
sumOfNumbers 0 = 0        
sumOfNumbers n = n + sumOfNumbers(n-1)
```

The pattern you're matching is `0` or `n`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use values on the left side of '=' the pattern matching appears:

```
sumOfNumbers :: Int -> Int
sumOfNumbers 0 = 0        
sumOfNumbers n = n + sumOfNumbers(n -1)
```

Comment: So this is the pattern matching version of it? But in order for it be pattern matching, shouldn't there be this underscore sign _ in the function ?

Comment: An underscore would be the same as the `n` in his last line if you wanted to discard the value of the argument, but since it's being used in the definition, you need to give it a name.